# Why does a php page refresh release session variable

Tags: javascript, php, session, session-variables, session-timeout

I am trying to release/unset a session variable after 2 minutes through `unsetsession.php`:

```
<?php

    session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 120)) {
    // last request was more than 2 minutes ago
    unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
    unset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']);
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp

?>
```

where the session variables are:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
```

However, the session variables do not get unset but are unset when I refresh the page. The page is making a call to the file unsetsession.php. Why is the session not getting unset after 2 minutes?

`EDIT`: The page `file.php` has `<?php include("includes/unsetsession.php") ?>` on top of the page. When `file.php` is refreshed on the browser, the value of the session variable `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;` gets changed to 0. It would not change after 2 mins. It only changes to 0 when the page is refreshed.

I am checking the value by running `getsession.php` on the browser which is:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
  echo "1";
  else
    echo "0";
?>
```

Comment: They aren't wrong. `-` operator has a higher priority than `>` so it's alright

Comment: @developerwjk it does destroy for me. I have a call to unsetsession.php in the page as `<?php include("includes/unsetsession.php") ?>`. Also the value does not get reset after the 2 minute expiry. Any pointers?

Comment: What do you mean by "they do not get unset but are unset when I refresh the page"? They should be unset if you refresh the page _and_ the refresh was made two minutes after the variable has been set.
Edit: your php script is only called once, when your page is loaded. That's why it only destroys the variable when you refresh it: it doesn't run the script if you don't refresh it

Comment: @developerwjk the code for unsetting the session - the one posted above in the qestion

Comment: @Angivare the code above is from `unsetsession.php`. The session variable does not get unset after 2 minutes. However whenever I refresh the page, the value is unset

Comment: Do you mean every time you refresh it gets unset or only after you refresh after 2 minutes?

Comment: @developerwjk it would get unset always; be it before 2 minutes or after. Please see edit to my question

Comment: Its something to do with another page. Just the code you posted, as one page, works fine. Its still not clear where you are including this page in another page, but that must be the problem, somehow.

Comment: @developerwjk does the `edit` make things any clear?

Comment: Ok, yes, it is fairly clear now. As Angivare has been saying, the code on the page only runs when you access it again (e.g. by refreshing it) so that makes sense as to why the value doesn't change until you refresh it. That's what its supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you clearly have a problem on understanding how *php* works.
Whenever you *load* your page,  your php script will be executed *once*.

So you're going through your code the first time, your session variable is set.
And now, it's **over**. Your php script has executed and it's just finished, it won't do anything anymore.

But if you *refresh* your page, the script will be called again.
That time, the session variable is already set, and let's say it has been two minutes. So you enter the condition and destroy it. And your second call to the script is finished.

---

So there's no really way on finding a solution to your problem right now, before you give us any more information on what you're trying to achieve.

Some solutions would be using javascript to regularly make an AJAX request to unsetsession.php for instance, or simply letting this as is: the session will not be unset until you load a page. That's not really a problem, most websites do it that way.

Comment: So you mean there is no way to expire a session, say for a user who has been idle on the website for sometime? also, why does the session expire on and/or before the interval value of 2 when we navigate else where on the website?

Comment: The session will not expire when being idle, but when browsing a page after having been idle (but you'll have to include unsetsession.php to _every page_ in your website). That's more or less the same thing. Just think of it like this: you're on page. You wait 2 minutes, and nothing happens. But if you try to go in another page, you'll be disconnected.
Now, you could make it so you get disconnected _while_ you're idle, using AJAX as stated in my answer.

Comment: @Sarah If the variable is expiring before 2 minutes even on a reload you need to state that in the problem. Also as mentioned you can use AJAX to call a PHP file, so for example you can have a `setTimeout()` that could call a PHP which unsets sessions.